# No Metadata Classes to process. creating schema

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to create my database , using symfony2 +Run command +doctrine:schema:create:...
but I have this message in my output : No Metadata Classes to process

PS: I tried to clear the cache. What should I do? Here is an example for my entity:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\EspritBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint as Assert;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Rayon {
/**
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;
/**
 *@ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */
private $libelle;
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getLibelle() {
    return $this->libelle;
}

public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function setLibelle($libelle) {
    $this->libelle = $libelle;
}

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I also tried creating the entities also automatically, using Doctrine. Check out my question and what I have tried, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257806/how-to-generate-db-tables-in-symfony-using-doctrine-created-in-app-using-php-a