# Error "No Metadata Classes to process." when generating DB tables in Symfony (using Doctrine) created using php app/console doctrine:generate:entity

Tags: php, symfony, console, doctrine, entity

Symfony newbie here! I installed Symfony and I made a controller and an action and some html is displayed properly. So, Symfony is working fine. I have a problem creating entity tables in the database. I created some entities using (annotations and some other way of making those - I tried couple of different ways of making entities through console, with same result). To create entities I used:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

And then, when I try to flush it to the database (in order to create the table(s)), I use this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

After running that command, I get this error, and - just as I expected - the tables are not created:

I tried to clear the symfony cache.
I checked AppBundle is registered in AppKernel.
I checked that auto mapping is set to true in entity manager.

What am I missing here? To remind you, I have just installed a fresh Symfony and did the steps I described above. I appreciate your help since I really need this because I want to learn Symfony.

Comment: Have you created the scheme? doctrine:scheme:create ??

Comment: No, I was unable to do that either. I deleted whole bundle, and created bundle through console, and then created tables through console, and this time it worked.

Comment: f you changed something in your Entity annotation clear Doctrine cache: app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata && app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query && app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

Comment: Any typo in the entity name or filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted whole bundle, and created bundle through console, and then created tables through console, and this time it worked. I still don't know what was wrong with my previous setting(s) of Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your config.yml(app/config.config.yml) you have configured your doctrine->orm->auto_mapping => true.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ----
        ----
    orm:
        ----
        ----
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: It is true. So this is not the problem.